# Stuck with a somewhat complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently quite stuck with my project on this SQL query that I can't get to work.

Here are my tables:

```
[INVENTORY]
====================================================
|  ITEM _ID  |  ITEM_DESC   |   STOCK   |    PPU   |
====================================================
|  1         |  CHAIR WHITE |      200  |    15.00 |
|  2         |  CHAIR BLACK |      150  |    15.00 |
|  3         |  CHAIR GREEN |      100  |    15.00 |
====================================================  

[I_RSV]
==============================================
|  ID  |  TRAN_CODE   |   ITEM_ID  |    QTY  |
==============================================
|   1  |  1001        |      1     |    100  |
|   2  |  1001        |      2     |     50  |
|   3  |  1002        |      1     |     50  |
==============================================

[TRANSACTIONS]
=========================================================
|  TRAN_CODE  |  TRAN_DATE   |   DATE_IN  |   DATE OUT  |
=========================================================
|  1001       |  5/22/2015   |  5/26/2015 |  5/27/2015  |
|  1002       |  5/22/2015   |  5/30/2015 |  5/31/2015  |
=========================================================
```

So the goal is to query ALL ITEM DETAILS and the SUM OF ALL RESERVED ITEMS THAT HASN'T PASSED TODAY'S DATE. This would be the goal in table form:

```
[TABLE X]
=============================================================
|  ITEM_ID  |  ITEM_DESC   |   PPU  |   STOCK  |  RESERVED  |
=============================================================
|  1        |  CHAIR WHITE |  15.00 |     200  |       150  |
|  2        |  CHAIR BLACK |  15.00 |     150  |        50  |
|  3        |  CHAIR GREEN |  15.00 |     100  |         0  |
=============================================================
```

So far this is what I had done:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_DESC, PPU, STOCK, (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM I_RSV WHERE 
DATE_OUT < GETDATE() GROUP BY ITEM_ID) FROM INVENTORY
```

But I can't seem to get it work. Any help would be appreciated so much.

Comment: `GETDATE()` is SQL Server (and sybase I think). I will tag this SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1. Separate the two queries.
2. Put your Selection logic into the inline query and sum the results.
3. Left join the two so that you can still see products that don't have any matching reservations.

You can do this in one bit query but I think you will find this works better for readability and ease of query construction.

```
Create table #INVENTORY (Item_ID int,Item_Desc varchar(50),Stock Int,PPU real);
Insert Into #INVENTORY values
 (1,'CHAIR WHITE',200,15.00)
,(2,'CHAIR BLACK',150,15.00)
,(3,'CHAIR GREEN',100,15.00)

Create Table #I_RSV (ID Int,Tran_Code int,Item_ID int,Qty Int)
Insert into #I_RSV values
(1,1001,1,100),(2,1001,2,50),(3,1002,1,50)

Create Table #TRANSACTIONS
(TRAN_CODE int,TRAN_DATE date, DATE_IN date, [DATE OUT] date)
Insert into #TRANSACTIONS Values
 (1001,'5/20/2015','5/20/2015','5/20/2015')
,(1002,'5/22/2015','5/30/2015','5/31/2015')

Select I.*,Case when R.Qty is null then 0 else R.Qty end as Reserved
from #INVENTORY as I
Left join
    (   select SUM(Qty) as Qty ,R.Item_ID
        from #I_RSV as R inner join #TRANSACTIONS as T 
        on R.Tran_Code=T.TRAN_CODE 
        Where T.[DATE OUT] < GETDATE()
        group by R.Item_ID) as R
    on R.Item_ID=I.Item_ID;

drop table #INVENTORY;
drop table #TRANSACTIONS;
drop table #I_RSV;
```

Comment: Don't forget that get date also includes time so if you use a date time field you will need to adjust the query slightly to account for that difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the three tables together in order for the query to function

```
SELECT INV.ITEM_ID, INV.ITEM_DESC, INV.PPU, INV.STOCK, SUM(I_RSV.QTY)
FROM INVENTORY INV 
    JOIN I_RSV ON I_RSV.ITEM_ID = INVENTORY.ITEM_ID
    JOIN TRANSACTIONS TRN ON I_RSV.TRAN_CODE = TRN.TRAN_CODE
WHERE TRN.TRAN_CODE.DATE_OUT < GETDATE()
GROUP BY INV.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: When you try to execute this query it will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`. See my query below:

```
SELECT 
      ITEM_ID, 
      ITEM_DESC, 
      PPU, 
      STOCK,
      SUM(QTY)[RESERVED]
FROM INVENTORY A
LEFT JOIN I_RSV B ON A.ITEM_ID=B.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS C ON B.TRAN_CODE=C.TRAN_CODE
WHERE DATE_OUT < GETDATE() 
GROUP BY ITEM_ID,ITEM_DESC,PPU,STOCK,[DATE OUT]
```

Comment: It works but how will it return records that aren't really currently reserved. (see edited)

Comment: See @Chris'o 's answer.

Comment: I mean, how will it return all rows from the inventory i tried this with the other joins, but it only returns items which have reservations records on them.

Comment: Change the `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Rigel1121 answer

```
SELECT 
      ITEM_ID, 
      ITEM_DESC, 
      PPU, 
      STOCK,
      SUM(QTY),
      STOCK - SUM(QTY) 'FREE TO RESERVE' --free from reservation qty
FROM INVENTORY A
INNER JOIN I_RSV B ON A.ITEM_ID=B.ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS C ON B.TRAN_CODE=C.TRAN_CODE
WHERE DATE_OUT < GETDATE() 
GROUP BY ITEM_ID,ITEM_DESC,PPU,STOCK,[DATE OUT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT INVENTORY.ITEM_ID, INVENTORY.ITEM_DESC, INVENTORY.STOCK, INVENTORY.PPU, SUM(I_RSV.QTY)
    FROM INVENTORY
    LEFT JOIN I_RSV
    ON INVENTORY.ITEM_ID = I_RSV.ITEM_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION
    ON TRANSACTION.TRAN_CODE = I_RSV.TRAN_CODE
    WHERE TRANSACTION.DATE_OUT > GETDATE()
    GROUP BY INVENTORY.ITEM_ID, INVENTORY.ITEM_DESC, INVENTORY.STOCK, INVENTORY.PPU
```

your `DATE_OUT < GETDATE()`  is wrong. where u dont want to pass today date you should `date_out> getdate()`. or your should put it as `GETDATE() < DATE_OUT` getdate = today < date out